# How do I check the version of a running service?

Tags: ubuntu, service, centos, version

I am trying to locate the version of a service that starts at bootup. For question sake lets say its "xyz". I am aware of the common actions for a service. I just need to locate what version that service is. I searched the man pages for the service action and came up with nothing. I need this command line for both Ubuntu and CentOS platforms.

I have tried something as simple as;

service xyz --version

or

./xyz -version  or ./xyz -v   ...etc

So far I have not be able to find anything (document, command, start, stop, etc) to provide this info.

Any suggestions are appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Do you know how the service(s) where installed? source/rpm/etc? If it's rpm you can do `rpm -q xyz` which will give the version info. If installed another way then most apps usually answer to `xyz --v` or `xyz -v` but it varies and there may not be a specific 100% foolproof way to check. You would need to look at the manpage for any given app and see how it should be queried.

Comment: I am not sure how it was installed but I will research it further. I did try the the --v, and the -v switch. It was clear from the output that it wasn't understood.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an RPM based system, then the command you have to use is:

```
rpm -q SERVICE
```